# Including and excluding source sets for different flavors in Android Studio

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio project I've got different java modules and want them to be compiled depending of product flavor (i.e. *feature1* in *flavor1* and *feature2, feature3* in *flavor2*). There is some *common* code as well, that needs to be compiled always.
Here is a part my build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += [
                      'path_to_my_dir/feature1'
            ]
        }
    }
    flavor2 {
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += [
                     'path_to_my_dir/feature2',
                     'path_to_my_dir/feature3'
            ]
        }
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir 'path_to_my_dir/common'
}
```

The issue is that *all* features compile for *any flavor*.
Different variants of code like this doesn't work either:

```
flavor2 {
        main.java.excludes += [
                 'path_to_my_dir/feature1'
        ]
    }
}
```

Any ideas of how to make it work?

Comment: Hi, i found the solution here https://bulldogjob.com/articles/1063-how-we-managed-to-build-18-android-apps-from-a-single-project and it works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works in a slightly different structure:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDir 'path_to_my_dir/common'
    }
    flavor1 {
        java.srcDirs += [
              'path_to_my_dir/feature1'
        ]
    }
    flavor2 {
        java.srcDirs += [
              'path_to_my_dir/feature2'
              'path_to_my_dir/feature3'
        ]
    }
}
```